# Geometry nodes How to fill the object with particles?

Tags: geometry-nodes

How can I fill the object with some points in geometry nodes? Point distribute node place dots on the surface, but I need them to be inside the object randomly

Comment: If I understand correctly this is not implemented yet, but it's got a [tracking issue](https://developer.blender.org/T85898).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if someone has a better answer but there is a way to fake volume for an object by using an array with Geometry nodes

1 You need to create your instances (a cube, a sphere o something similar), an empty and your main object to fill.

2 On your main object, you need to add an array modifier and below this, the Geometry nodes

3 Inside your array modifier, increase the count, select "Object Offset" and add your empty as the offset.

4 Inside the geometry nodes add a point distribute, point scale and point instance.

5 Make the Empty offset smaller to create the illusion of having instances inside the main object.

[image]

[image]

Comment: this does not really work....it looks good in your picture because you made the cubes that big. But inside is nearly no cube...

Comment: @Chris You need to make the empty smaller, the empty is the one making the ilusion of volume because it's controlling the position of the array, i will update the image to an animated gif so you can see how this works. the smaller the cubes, the more you will need